# Slash command registers command from wrong folder discord.js14

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm tired of trying to solve this. First off, here is my deployment code

```js
const { REST, Routes } = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('node:fs');
const { client_id } = require('./config.json')

const commands = [];
// Grab all the command files from the commands directory you created earlier
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./slashCommands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

// Grab the SlashCommandBuilder#toJSON() output of each command's data for deployment
for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./slashCommands/${file}`);
  commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}

// Construct and prepare an instance of the REST module
const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(process.env.TOKEN);

// and deploy your commands!
(async () => {
  try {
    console.log(`Started refreshing ${commands.length} application (/) commands.`);

    // The put method is used to fully refresh all commands in the guild with the current set
    const data = await rest.put(
      Routes.applicationCommands(client_id),
      { body: commands },
    );

    console.log(`Successfully reloaded ${data.length} application (/) commands.`);
  } catch (error) {
    // And of course, make sure you catch and log any errors!
    console.error(error);
  }
})();
```

It is supposed to get the command from the "slashCommand" folder. So I run 'node deploy-commands.js' and it works.
The problem is when I do the slash command '/ping', I get this error:

```
/home/runner/Nocinel/commands/ping.js:8
    message.reply(' **Ball is going over the net...**').then(m => { m.edit(`** Pong!\n:stopwatch: Uptime: ${Math.round(message.client.uptime / 60000)} minutes\n:sparkling_heart: Websocket Heartbeat: ${message.client.ws.ping}ms\n:round_pushpin: Rountrip Latency: ${m.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp}ms**`) });
                                                                        ^

TypeError: m.edit is not a function
    at /home/runner/Nocinel/commands/ping.js:8:73
repl process died unexpectedly: exit status 1
```

Now this error indicates that I am running a command from my "command" folder rather than my "slashCommand" folder. Which doesnt make sense because I explicitly coded it to only get commands from the "slash command folder"

I have restarted, deleted, waited for an hour, and tested it multiple times, it always gives the same disappointing result. I see absolutely nothing wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with registring comannd (deploy-comannds.js is only registring comannds not using making them work). Problem have to be in your index.js you have to handle interaction comannds to your folder slashComannds. Registring comannds was sucessfull.

Documentation:
https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-handling.html#loading-command-files

Comment: oh my lord. my command handler is set to `interaction.clients.commands.get` instead of `interaction.clients.slashCommands.get`. This might actually work now, I'll test it once my bot is active again.

Comment: Sadly, it did not work :c. My cmd handler and interactionCreate event looks fine :C

Comment: @Lenin Can i ask you for code where you are handlering interaction. Propably index.js

Comment: After a few trial and errors, i found that the problem was really in my slashcommand handler. thanks. its all fixed